# Reactjs container with readonlyrootvolume true in aws fargate taskdef is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a ReactJS UI container with the readonlyrootvolume flag set to false. However, according to AWS Security Hub complaints, the flag is supposed to be true. Therefore, we updated readonlyrootvolume to true and attached the tmp volume in the AWS Fargate task definition. After enabling the readonlyrootvolume, the nodejs application is not working and getting error

*47 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden,

Comment: "However, according to AWS Security Hub complaints, the flag is supposed to be true" That's a recommendation, not an absolute rule.